# Undesirable behavior in SQL SERVER 2005

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-2005

I have got an MVC4 application that basically performs some CRUD  functions using forms in views.
However I am  getting really weird results  when I perform a simple sql insert by submitting a form. Essentially, I should only have one single record inserted  into the db  but  what I find is that I get rows added  randomly to some other table that I haven't run queries for(almost like it is running a  previous query)

My guess  is that SQL sever is caching previous queries including sprocs and running them randomly in the background

I have tried to perform the same insert query on production without any hassle but i get these random additions when I'm testing on the test server.

Has anyone faced a similar issue and is there a recommend way of dealing with situations like these? I  have already tried restarting sql service, and meticulously  checking my code to no avail.

Comment: It seems unlikely that SQL Server is caching previous queries and executing them randomly; I suspect someone would have noticed something like that by now. Do you have any triggers in the database that might be executing additional queries? Are you using Entity Framework? If you are creating the ObjectContext/DbContext and keeping it around at application scope that could cause a problem like this.

Comment: Use profiler.  Give your connection string a unique "Application Name" in your application.  Then you can see both what procedures/sql is running, and if your app (using Application Name in the sql server connection string) is the offending party.

Comment: I'm not using the entity framework. I'm using dapper for ORM.I have used sql profiler  and all I could find where the same queries I would expect and nothing strange.Surely if it works on the live server, it should work on the test server ?  :(

Comment: I figured out the  problem  here. The issue  was that the databases between production and  testing were out of  sync  as  we  sync them  regularly  with  SQL data compare to facilitate real  world testing.user id's  were out of  sync which is  why  it  seemed like  data was being added randomly.So new users where being created with id's  that already existed in  a referenced  table because these tables were synced  at different times.